# Discrete Fourier Time Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $x[0]=1, x[1]=1, x[2]=1, x[3]=1, x[n]=0$ for $n \geq 4$, find the DFT of $$\{x[n]\}=( x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3] )$$.

My method of doing this is to use the DFT formula as defined here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Digital_Signal_Processing/Discrete_Fourier_Transform

So we get the sum from $0 \to 3$ of $x[n] \times e^{\large{\frac{-2 \pi i kn}{4}}}$

So we get: $$\large{1 \times e^{\frac{-2 \pi i k \times 0}{4}} + ... +1 \times e^{\large{\frac{-2 \pi i k \times 3}{4}}}}$$

Is my thinking correct? (sorry I haven't used tex- dont know how to!)

Thanks